# Monitor file changes

Tags: monitoring, tracking

In a Linux environment, which one is the best way to monitor daily the files changes in a particular list of folders?

Each folder will have subdirectories which need to be checked too.

At the moment I'm using the command `find` with the `-mtime` parameter.

Comment: Git sounds like a good solution for your needs.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Are you looking for changes and changes are evidence of a security problem?  Or is this for syncing?  Or something else? This is potentially off-topic, but if you are looking to monitor changes where there should not be any, take a look at a HIDS solution - there are some Open Source ones like OSSEC

Comment: @schroeder, I need to monitor even folder which are not tracked by git, nevertheless git can be compromised.

Comment: @crovers, the idea is monitoring for security reasons, so more info I can have, better is for who needs to look at the reports. An output git-like, would be very useful.

Comment: you could git your whole file system (omitting the obvious directories) - if you have requirements, then you need to include them in your question

Answer (score 5):

I like to use **OSSEC**, it has many options:

> OSSEC watches it all, actively monitoring all aspects of Unix system
>   activity with file integrity monitoring, log monitoring, rootcheck,
>   and process monitoring. With OSSEC you won't be in the dark about what
>   is happening to your valuable computer system assets.

https://ossec.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

## Maybe TripWire

[TripWire](https://www.tripwire.org/) says it can do this. Haven't tried.

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Source_Tripwire):

> When first initialized, Open Source Tripwire scans the file system as directed by the administrator and stores information on each file scanned in a database. At a later date the same files are scanned and the results compared against the stored values in the database. Changes are reported to the user. Cryptographic hashes are employed to detect changes in a file without storing the entire contents of the file in the database.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, aside from your lack of sureness. TripWire is exactly what OP is looking for. I have used it on a number of systems to monitor critical areas (e.g. htdocs on a web server).

Comment: @Polynomial: Guessing too much like a link-only-answer. *shrugs*

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @StackzOfZtuff, TripWire is one of the recommended tool for File integrity management. It will generate report of all the changes for specified directories.

http://www.tripwire.com/solutions/file-integrity-and-change-monitoring/

Other option is setting up a cron job on your machine which will be running at a particular frequency to analyze any diff in the files.

Answer (score 0):

Tripwire applies, but it's learning-usability curve can be unkind.

OSSEC applies but has wider goals and implications than simply FIM - which may be a good thing, may be a bad thing, depends on where you are.

For point solutions (servers not server farms) I prefer [**AIDE**](http://aide.sourceforge.net/).  I think of it as a much simpler version of Tripwire, and depending on where you're using it, sometimes simplicity is preferred.